# Why Can't I Call Drupal Function From .inc File?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have an inc file which I am including in my module using module_load_include. It contains the following function:

```
function _get_vid($vocabulary_name) {
    $vocabs = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
    foreach ($vocabs as $vocab_object) {
        if ($vocab_object->name == $vocabulary_name) {
           return $vocab_object->vid;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

But PHP keeps complaining that taxonomy_get_vocabularies is an undefined function. Why? I know I've used Drupal functions in .inc files before with no issues.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: From which function is `_get_vid()` called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your module must have weight higher than the taxonomy module so that I can call any functions that are defined in taxonomy.

You can make sure your module is the heaviest one in order to run last by implementing [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7).
You would create a file **yourmodule.install** in your module folder which may contain the following code:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_install()
 */
function yourmodule_install(){
    # Fetch max module weight from "system" table.
    $max_weight = db_query("SELECT MAX(weight) FROM {system} WHERE type = 'module'")->fetchField();
    # Make sure this module is the heaviest one in order to run last
    db_update('system')
        ->fields(array('weight' => $max_weight+1))
        ->condition('name', 'yourmodule')
        ->execute();
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_uninstall()
 */
function yourmodule_uninstall(){
    db_delete('system')
        ->condition('name', 'yourmodule')
        ->execute();    
}
```

Comment: I can call taxonomy_get_vocabularies() from within my .module file just fine. If it works there then shouldn't it work in a .inc file too?

Comment: Yeah I just tried your suggestion (I even checked out the database myself to make sure that my module had a higher weight than everything), and the problem remains.

Comment: Actually your suggestion was correct. I just had to flush the cache first, whoops.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to tell you to clear the cache. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 version of taxonomy_get_vocabularies doesn't accept parameter $type. See the documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_vocabularies/7). Might be that.. Try with out passing NULL parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the issue. PHP is complaining that the function is not even defined.

I made the change you suggested and the problem remains.

Comment: Hmmm yeah.. I just added code <?php

$vocabs = taxonomy_get_vocabularies(NULL);
drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($vocabs) . "</pre>");
?> and it worked... I am sure it's some thing else... Post your module_load_include code..

Comment: module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'inc/taxonomies');